# Can’t connect to Apache webserver via HTTPS (HTTP works just fine)

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, webserver, ssl, xampp

I’m running a XAMPP 5.6.3 installation on my desktop Windows 8.1 system, and I have an issue with connecting to the Apache webserver. I can still connect normally through port 80 and HTTP, but if I use HTTPS, I time out, even on `localhost`. My firewall doesn't seem to be blocking anything, and I can connect via `telnet <address> <port>` just fine.

I can’t seem to find the issue, it seems that all of my settings (and ports) are correct and there’s nothing wrong with the actual SSL module loading up. In the logs, it doesn’t show any connection errors when I connect from `localhost` or my actual domain and it says that it loads the SSL engine and the certificates just fine.

I’m not really sure what's wrong based off of the logs I could browse. My logs and configuration files [can be found here](http://pastebin.com/u/TehTotalPwnage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open manualy the 443 port in your firewall . If you are using internet security software check this also

Comment: Wow, I did not think that AVG was the culprit. Thanks! Now to figure out how to get AVG to stop screwing around with my certificates.